# Package dependencies from a local pypi repository

Tags: python, pip, distutils

i have googled for an answer but i did not find anything really matching my needs (but i might be wrong).

We have a local Pypi repository that we need to use for our dependencies.

I am trying to use `dependency_links`, but apparently that's deprecated, plus, this is not working.

I have found lots of confusing posts about github.com repositories, which are not what i need to achieve (that's pretty easy); my problem is using another pypi index-url for our packages.

Thanks

Comment: So you want *only* to use the local repo? Have you updated your `.pypirc`? See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html#the-pypirc-file

Comment: Do you have any requirement for what version of `pip`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, i don't want to use only my local repo, and i need to adopt a solution that will make the package install. I will be installing this package on servers, so having an account-related pypirc file is not a thing. I might maybe use a setup.cfg ? Or can i use pypirc file in package as well ?

Comment: @Grimmy no, no specific requirement.

Comment: Think I understand now. You want to reference the custom dependencies in setup.py. dependency_links is not deprecated, but it only supports URLs so you are limited to sdist (no wheels).

Comment: Personally I just install dependencies using requirements files. I separate them into public and private and just run them with pip. That happens in a Dockerfile in the build system. `--index-url` does the job.

Comment: ... and I guess if you are running devpi, it will act as both a mirror and a private repo, so you can fetch all packages from it.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to make pip install packages from a private repository is to pass the [`--extra-index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#extra-index-url) option (or, if you don't even want anything from pypi.python.org installed, [`--index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#index-url)) to the `pip install` command, e.g.:

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://local-pypi.example.com/simple private-pkg
```

Comment: Hi, i understand. But what if the private-pkg has a dependency which is on the private repository itself ? Will this work ?

Comment: @BrunoRipa: I believe so.  Try it and see.

Comment: `pip install -f repository_url --trusted-host repository_domain package` does the trick. Thanks